# Graph for Train and Validation set (overfitting?)

Tags: python, boosting

[image]

I'm using xgb and have hypertuned my parameters using hyperopt, however when I plot the the train set and validation set after fitting my model, I noticed that the lines intersect with each other, what does that mean? Also the validation line doesn't start near the training line.

I'm using `early_stopping_rounds = 20` when I fit my model prior to plotting this graph.

The hyperparameters I got from HyperOpt are as follows:

> {'booster': 'gbtree',
> 'colsample_bytree': 0.8814444518931106,
> 'eta': 0.0712456143241873,
> 'eval_metric': 'ndcg',
> 'gamma': 0.8925113465433823,
> 'max_depth': 8,
> 'min_child_weight': 5,
> 'objective': 'rank:pairwise',
> 'reg_alpha': 2.2193560083517383,
> 'reg_lambda': 1.8600142721064354,
> 'seed': 0,
> 'subsample': 0.9818535865621624}

I thought Hyperopt should be giving me the best parameters. What can I possibly change to improve this?

*Edit*

I changed n_estimators from 527 to 160, and it is giving me this graph now.
But I'm not sure if this graph is okay? Any advice is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Looks like the model is overfitting to the training data past the cross-over point. If this is as good as it gets after hyperparameter tuning, you probably need to stop training after 170-180 epochs.

Comment: What is your `eval_metric` that `early_stopping` uses?

Comment: @pavel Hi, thanks for responding to my post. eval_metric is ndcg, early_stopping_rounds is 20, initially the n_estimators I used from hyperopt was 527. I have attempted to change n_estimators to 160, now the two lines are touching each other at 160, for a good model, should both of the lines converge at the same point? 
Does it matter if my validation line doesn't start close to my training line? It seems like a very straight line. (I've also edited my post as per above)

Comment: Normally there should almost always be a crossover point. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#:~:text=In%20statistics%20and%20machine%20learning,bias%20in%20the%20estimated%20parameters.&text=The%20variance%20is%20an%20error,fluctuations%20in%20the%20training%20set.